# How can I create a spherical perspective grid in Photoshop or Illustrator

Tags: adobe-photoshop, adobe-illustrator, perspective

How can I create a spherical perspective grid (six point perspective) in Photoshop or Illustrator CS5 where the poles are shown on the top and the bottom (exactly like the image below).

I have explored the 'polar grid tool' in Illustrator and the 'Vanishing Point' filter in Photoshop. Neither of these tools are able to create this kind of perspective grid.

If possible I would like to find a method that allows customizations like, setting the number of concentric and radial dividers like how the 'polar grid tool' works, rather than trying to build it with shapes or something..

Thanks for any help

EDIT: I have learned that this is referred to as ***Six Point Perspective.***

EDIT: [reference image source](http://www.ps.uci.edu/~tomba/sk/tscan/desc/), in case its at all useful

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In **Illustrator**....

Draw a half circle....

Choose `Effect > 3D > Revolve...` And adjust the options....

[image]

There is no method to control the amount of plane division in the 3D Effect. But you can always expand the art and manually add additional division.

Comment: Hi Scott.Your solution is very close but not quite there. I find it hard to describe the difference between the two, but I think its to do with the viewpoint. In you solution the viewer is looking at a sphere from outside. In the reference I provided its like the viewer is inside the sphere looking across the internal space to the far side... its slightly different. By the way, I was able to increase the number of dividers with 3D > revolve simply by creating a larger half circle shape to begin with. I updated the post with a link to the reference image source, in case that helps.

Comment: The ops image is 0 degree rotation but instead has a perspective angle!

Comment: Do you know what software to use to create a wireframe / grid like in the op joojaa? If it cant be done in Photoshop or Illustrator do you have any ideas about what program could be used to do it?